# PHP Roster only showing one player on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to put together a guild roster for my WoW guilds website.  I have the roster pulling all of the right information and listing it in a table properly.  The next step is to pop up a modal and display more information when clicking on one of my guild members names in the list.

Unfortunately, when I click on anyone's name in the list it only displays information of the first person in the list.  Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

So you can see what I mean, go to the following link and click on any random players name in the table.  No matter who you choose, it will display information about "Alisyn":
http://www.astalder.net/roster.php

Here is part of the code:

```
//Guild Roster Table Headers
echo " <div width='600px' align#'center'>";
echo '
<div align="center" id="roster" class="roster" style="float: none;">
<table class="warcraft sortable" border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Race/Class</strong></a></th>
<th width="140px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Name</strong></a></th>
<th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Level</strong></a></th>
<th width="140px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Rank</strong></a></th>
<!-- <th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Message</strong></a></th> -->
</tr>';

//Character Arrays
foreach($rows as $p) {
$mrank = $p['rank'];
$mname = $p['name'];
$mclass = $p['class'];
$mrace = $p['race'];
$mlevel = $p['level'];
$mgender = $p['gender'];
$mthumbnail = $p['thumbnail'];

echo "<div id='myModal' class='reveal-modal'>
    <h1><center>Details for " . $mname . "</center></h1>
    <p>Name: " . $mname . "<br />
    Class: " . $mclass . "<br /></p>
    <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
</div>";

//@$json = file_get_contents("http://$region.battle.net/api/wow/character/$realm/$mname?fields=items", true);
//$decode = json_decode($json, true);

//$milvl = " ". $decode['items']['averageItemLevel'] . "";

//Table of Guild Members
echo "
<tr>
<td align='center'><strong><img style=\"padding-left: 5px;\" src=\"race/race_$mrace-$mgender.jpg\"></img><img style=\"padding-left: 5px;\" src=\"class/class_$mclass.jpg\"></img></strong></td>
<!-- <td class='class_$mclass' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><strong><a href=\"http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/stormrage/$mname/advanced\" target=\"_blank\">$mname<span><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\" alt=\"$mname\" height=\"100\"></span></a></strong></div></td> -->
<td class='class_$mclass' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><strong><a href=\"#\" class=\"big-link\" data-reveal-id=\"myModal\" target=\"_blank\">$mname<span><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\" alt=\"$mname\" height=\"100\"></span></a></strong></div></td>
<td width=\"80px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><strong>$mlevel</strong></td>
<td sorttable_customkey='$mrank' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><strong>$ranks[$mrank]</strong></td>
<!-- <td width=\"90px\" aligh=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\"></div></td> -->
</tr>
";
}
echo " </table></div>";
```

Comment: Did you wrote some js to do this? If yes, can you please add the code.

Comment: Reference the rows by their unique id's. Hence when you click the name, the respective ID will be called and the player info will be displayed as per that id.

Comment: @Dinistro:  It is using jquery-reveal.

Comment: Its doing that because all your modals have the same ID, this must be unique, also there is no need to create a separate modal for each char, have one bare bone and populate it with data onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the rows by their unique id's. Hence when you click the name, the respective ID will be called and the player info will be displayed as per that id:

```
//Guild Roster Table Headers
echo " <div width='600px' align#'center'>";
echo '
<div align="center" id="roster" class="roster" style="float: none;">
<table class="warcraft sortable" border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Race/Class</strong></a></th>
<th width="140px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Name</strong></a></th>
<th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Level</strong></a></th>
<th width="140px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Rank</strong></a></th>
<!-- <th width="80px" align="center" valign="top" ><strong>Message</strong></a></th> -->
</tr>';

//Character Arrays
foreach($rows as $i=>$p) {
$mrank = $p['rank'];
$mname = $p['name'];
$mclass = $p['class'];
$mrace = $p['race'];
$mlevel = $p['level'];
$mgender = $p['gender'];
$mthumbnail = $p['thumbnail'];

echo "<div id='myModal_$i' class='reveal-modal'>
    <h1><center>Details for " . $mname . "</center></h1>
    <p>Name: " . $mname . "<br />
    Class: " . $mclass . "<br /></p>
    <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
</div>";

//@$json = file_get_contents("http://$region.battle.net/api/wow/character/$realm/$mname?fields=items", true);
//$decode = json_decode($json, true);

//$milvl = " ". $decode['items']['averageItemLevel'] . "";

//Table of Guild Members
echo "
<tr>
<td align='center'><strong><img style=\"padding-left: 5px;\" src=\"race/race_$mrace-$mgender.jpg\"></img><img style=\"padding-left: 5px;\" src=\"class/class_$mclass.jpg\"></img></strong></td>
<!-- <td class='class_$mclass' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><strong><a href=\"http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/stormrage/$mname/advanced\" target=\"_blank\">$mname<span><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\" alt=\"$mname\" height=\"100\"></span></a></strong></div></td> -->
<td class='class_$mclass' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><strong><a href=\"#\" class=\"big-link\" data-reveal-id=\"myModal_$i\" target=\"_blank\">$mname<span><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\" alt=\"$mname\" height=\"100\"></span></a></strong></div></td>
<td width=\"80px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><strong>$mlevel</strong></td>
<td sorttable_customkey='$mrank' width=\"140px\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><strong>$ranks[$mrank]</strong></td>
<!-- <td width=\"90px\" aligh=\"center\" valign=\"top\" ><div class=\"hover_img\"><img src=\"http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/$mthumbnail\"></div></td> -->
</tr>
";
}
echo " </table></div>";
```